# Checking for the existence of files against a list

Tags: bash, files

I have a "command" text file that issues a data file download command on each
    line.   I send the command file to bash.  However, a small percentage of the downloads fail.  Here is the algorithm I use to find out what's missing:

1. After downloading, I go back through the command file and check if each download file exists.
2. If the download doesn't exist, I copy the command line into a new command file.
3. I am left with a new command file for the remaining downloads.

Here is the bash script I implemented the algorithm with:

```
  1 #!/bin/bash
  2 while read line
  3 do
  4         for item in $line
  5         do
  6                 if [[ $item == *out_fname* ]]; then 
  7                         splitline=(${item//=/ })   
  8                         target_file=${splitline[1]}
  9                         if [ ! -f $target_file ]; then
 10                                 echo $line >> stillneed.txt
 11                         fi
 12                 fi
 13         done
 14 done < "$@"
```

Question:  This works well, but is there a better algorithm or implementation (maybe using something other than bash)?  What I did was just have bash do what a human would have to do.  But it seems Unix always has a better way of doing things...

Comment: If you give some examples of the line being read in, then we could give some more efficient algorithms.

Comment: as you deduced `out_fname=myfile.txt` is the relevant command-line argument

Comment: `< "$@"` will fail with more than 1 arg.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you are looking for 'out_fname=', not just 'out_fname'.

I'd either do this in a mix of awk and shell or in python. In awk/shell:

```
awk '{for(i=0;i<NF;i++) {if (index($i, 'out_fname=')) {split($i,A,/=/);print A[i]}}' "$@" |
    while read filename; do
        if [ ! -f $filename ]; then echo $filename; fi
    done > stillneed.txt
```

In python:

```
import fileinput, os
stillneed = open("stillneed.txt", "w")
for line in fileinput.input():
    for filename in [l.split('=')[1] for l in line.split() if l.find('out_fname=')!=-1]:
        if not os.path.exists(filename):
            print >>stillneed, filename
```

Answer (score 1):

not sure if it'll help but I have a function to retry commands until they return a success:

```
retry () {
    local delay=1 n

    if ! [[ $1 = *[^0-9]* ]]; then
        # TODO allow delay=0 (prevents Ctrl-C)
        if (($1 > 0)); then
            delay=${1:1}
        fi
        shift
    fi

    # run command
    while ! "$@"; do
        echo "retrying in ${delay}s"
        for ((n=delay; n>0; n--)); do
            sleep 1 || return
        done
    done
}; export -f retry
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of checking what's missing after the initial download script has completed, consider adding some checks to said download script. I have not tested the following, I just wrote it off the top of my head:

```
cat files_to_download|while read file; 
do
    SUCCESS="False"
    while [[ $SUCCESS == "False" ]];
    do
        wget $file;
        if [[ $? -eq 0 ]];
        then
            SUCCESS="True"
        fi
   done
done
```

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend `echo`ing a copy of the line when the download fails, rather than reviewing the filenames by parsing each line in the file afterwards:

```
[[ -f $1 ]] || { echo "$1 not found" >&2; exit 1; }
while read -r line; do
    $line || echo "$line" >> stillneed
done < "$1"
```

That would be more efficient, and also means you don't need to worry about any odd filenames in the future (eg with spaces in.)

If you want to improve your existing method, you could use standard parameter expansion:

```
for f; do
    while read -r line; do
        for item in $line; do
            [[ $item = out_fname=* ]] || continue
            [[ -f ${item#out_fname=} ]] || echo "$line"
            break # assuming one fname per line
        done
    done < "$f"
done > stillneed
```

..but consider what happens with: `out_fname='foo bar.ext'`. Also, bear in mind that this checks every line after the event, when we could just have checked whether the command worked at the time we ran it.

Opening `stillneed` once for the whole loop is more efficient; I didn't do that in the first snippet as we'd most likely want to see output from the download commands. Here there's only tests, no external commands running so it makes sense to open the file once. (Note using `>` will truncate the file at the start; I've used `for f` to allow more than one input file as positional parameters: adding the same above should be easy if you need it.)

The one thing I must stress is quoting: `echo "$line"` is very different from `echo $line`. In general, quote **all** parameter expansions (this includes variables) unless you know for sure that you want field-splitting to happen.